# Nesting MYSQLi functions

Tags: php, mysqli

This question refers to nesting mysqli functions. I'm not sure the term "nesting" is the correct one here so i'll explain.
Look at this code for example:

```
$query = 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE id="' . $_POST['uid'] . '"';
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$user_id = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
```

The code above can be turned into a *shorthand* version as follows:

```
$user_id = mysqli_fetch_row($mysqli->query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE id="' . $_POST['uid'] . '"'));
```

I know this works because I've tried it. I see that PHP is taking care of the code from "inside-out", is it basically a recursive method to write this code or am I completely off with the terms?

My question is this, does this work for all MYSQL commands or PHP functions? are there exceptions for this functionality? what are the drawbacks to using such form? (besides it being less *readable* by a programmer)

EDIT: I know the query is not a prepared statement.

Comment: Mysql here is irrelevant, it is just a matter of parameter evaluation.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari I would appreciate if you could elaborate and answer not as comment. Thanks.

Comment: One major drawback is that you can hardly do any sensible form of error control with the “short” version. The query might fail for any reason, which in the first version means $result would be false, which you can check for before trying to fetch rows from it, so that you can output an appropriate error message to the user, or sth. like that. The “short” version will just “crash”, and give you no chance to intervene and handle this situation appropriately.

Comment: @CBroe so Error handling, I see, well, that seems like a good enough reason not to use it already. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In order to call a function or class method, PHP has to evaluate all of its supplied parameters.

In this case, given the statement:

```
$user_id = mysqli_fetch_row($mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = $_POST[uid]"));
```

- in order to call `mysqli_fetch_row` PHP will first evaluate its argument, that is `$mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = $_POST[uid]")`
- in order to call `$mysqli->query` PHP will first evaluate its argument, that is `"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = $_POST[uid]"`
- now PHP will pass the query string to `$mysqli->query` and return the result set (or error maybe)
- that return value will be passed to `mysqli_fetch_row`

I would say that this is not PHP specific, but a quite general behaviour in parameter evaluation.

However it has one major drawback: you forego any kind of error checking which, especially when dealing with databases, is very important.

Comment: Thank you Matteo!

Comment: This is indeed not php specific, most programming languages with built-in memory management can chain function calls. However, languages where the programmer must manage the memory (such as C) can't do this.